# How to use a bom in both parent and child without replicating it in multiple places

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-bom

I have a parent child maven project structure. I want to use a few dependencies from

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
  </parent>
```

in both parent and child. (If jar1, jar2, jar3 are in the above bom, assume I want to use jar1, jar2 in parent and jar3 in child).

So in this case, I tried to include the above bom in the parent's `dependencyManagement` and inside that in `dependencies` section, but it doesn't seem to be available in the child pom. (Because, I was getting version not found for jar3 in the child project).

So should I replicate the above bom in both parent and child project or is there any work around ?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the BOM to the `<dependencyManagement>` of the parent, the versions are also available in the child project. There is no need to repeat the BOM.

Comment: For some reason I was getting version not found for that dependency (ex: jar 3) in the child project. Is there anything else that needs to be added ?

Comment: No. Maybe this is just a typo.